# Is there a Postgres feature or built-in function that limits the display of uuids to only that needed to make them uniquely identifiable?

Tags: sql, postgresql, guid

It would have to return the portion necessary to uniquely identify the row even if a select statement didn't return all rows, of course, to be of any use. And I'm not sure how it would work if the uuid column were not part of a pk/index and was repeated.

Does this exist?

Comment: There's nothing built-in. You would need to maintain some sort of speicalised prefix tree index for them and of course between the time of you reading the shortened key and later trying to use it that short version could be invalidated. You obviously couldn't use it anywhere else in the database at all. I'm struggling to see how you might use this.

Comment: Obviously this would be for select-only statements. Would mostly be to keep a report a little less crowded but still include the key. Sort of how git only shows the first few hex of an md5.

Comment: Except by the time I read the report the key displayed might not be unique any more. If you don't care about uniqueness then you could just display the last 4 characters or whatever, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would have to decide what constitutes uniquely identifiable by assuming that a number of places from the right make it uniquely identifiable.  I think this is folly but the way you would do that is something like this:

```
SELECT RIGHT(uuid_column_name::text, 7) as your_truncated_uuid FROM table_with_uuid_column;
```

That takes the 7 places from the right of the text value of the uuid column.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not. A UUID is a hex representation of a 120 bit random number, at least the v4 variant. It's not even *guaranteed* to be unique though it likely is.

You have a few options to implement this:

- shave off characters and hope you don't introduce a collision. For instance, if you make `d8366842-8c1d-4a31-a4c0-f1765b8ab108` `d8366842`, you have 16**8 possible combinations, or 4,294,967,296. how likely is your dataset to have a collision with 4.2 billion (2**32) possibilities? Perhaps you can add `8c1d` back in to make it 16**12 or 28,147,497,6710,656 possibilities.
- process and hash each row looking for collisions and recursively increase the frame of characters until no collisions are found, or hash every possible permutation.

That all said, another idea is to use ints and not uuids and then to use http://hashids.org/ which has a plugin for PostgreSQL. This is the method YouTube uses afaik.